# Get the pid and return status from nohup + sudo

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, sudo, nohup

I have a shell snippet:

```
nohup sudo node server.js >> node.log 2>&1 &

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $! $?
  echo $! > pids
fi
```

What I expect is if the `node server.js` run normaly, then record the pid of this process to the file: pids.

But it does'nt work, the `$?` is always 0 because it is the status of sudo process?
And the `$!` is also not the pid of the process of `node` command.

So how can I get the correct return code and pid of the `node server.js` in the above shell script?

Comment: You should run the script with sudo instead. Executing sudo within scripts is a bad practice.

Comment: why dont you use forever.js ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My final solutions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ROOT=$(cd `dirname $0`; pwd)

sudo kill -9 `cat ${ROOT}/pids` || true

nohup sudo node server.js >> node.log 2>&1 &

sleep 1

pid=$(ps --ppid $! | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')

if echo $pid | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$'; then
    echo $pid > ${ROOT}/pids
else
    echo 'server not started!'
fi
```

Comment: You might want to post this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are too many things to comment on to do it here.

Comment: On RH Linux, I change your line pid=$(ps --ppid $! | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }') by pid=$(ps -e | grep $! | awk '{ print $1 }') to get pid. Your line returns me the first word in the header which is PID

Comment: You save the pid in a file to kill it later. What if node is stopped, another process start and take the same pid saved in the file? you kill it !

Comment: This solution is perfectly work well. Wow.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a command in the background, there's no sensible way for the shell to get the return code without `wait`ing for the process to finish (i.e., `node` is no longer running). Therefore even these have return code 0:

```
$ false &
$ does_not_exist &
```

It seems what you want to do is to [check whether a daemon started properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#Starting_a_.22daemon.22_and_checking_whether_it_started_successfully), which completely depends on the daemon. In your case you've started a Node.js server, so you could simply run something like this (untested):

```
test_if_server_is_running() {
    tries=10
    while [ "$tries" -gt 0 ]
    do
        let tries--
        wget http://127.0.0.1/some_server_path && return
        sleep 1
    done
    return 1 # Did not start up in at least 10 seconds
}
```

Comment: using `wget` to check is also a useful way. :). thanks.